# Unreal Engine 4.27 buoyancy system not working (4.26.2 big issues also)

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to create a ship simulator within `Unreal Engine (4.27)` I tried to use `Water plugin` as also its content to start from and shorten the time to get it working.
I created an empty game project loaded `Water/Maps/WaterTestMap` then added an istance of `Water/Blueprints/BP_BuoyancyExample` to simulation (above sea level) and started the simulation... it just sink like anything else. I tried to modify some `Buoyancy data` parameters but it just seems that no forces are applied to the body.

I tried again on `4.26.2`, using water plugin contents, and it seems to work but if I try to create a floating cube BP that mimics `BP_BuoyancyExample` (in the same level as above) it sinks all the times… the only way to make it work is to use `EditorCube` as static mesh.

I cannot understand where’s the fault but it really sounds like a wonderful bug…

Comment: The problem related to 4.27 is probably given by an error during installing.

Comment: In 4.26.2 anyway abnormal behaviours of buoyancy are common and unpredictable.

Comment: What is the `Water plugin`?  There are many in the marketplace. This is a question better asked of the Author of the plug-in than here.

Comment: @Strom I meant the official *Unreal* `Water plugin`.